# jQuery fade in active element, fade out inactive elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, opacity

## Update

Using:

```
$(event.currentTarget).fadeTo(0, 1);
```

Seems to work, while using:

```
$('.btn .active').fadeTo(0, 1);
```

Does not. Any idea why?

### The Code

jsFiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/SeanKilleen/fwerK/

JavasScript code below:

```
var global_loggedOnUser = "User1";

$(document).ready(function () {

    var viewmodel = (function () {
        this.feedbacktype = ko.observable("None");
        this.currentPage = ko.observable(location.href);
        this.currentUsername = global_loggedOnUser;

        this.updateFeedbackType = function (item, event) {
            var newText = $(event.currentTarget).children("span").text();
            $('#buttonList button').removeClass('active');
            $(event.currentTarget).addClass('active');

            feedbacktype(newText);
            $('.btn').not('.active').fadeTo('fast', 0.3);
            $('.btn .active').fadeTo('fast', 1);
        };



        return {
            pageUserIsOn: currentPage,
            theUser: currentUsername,
            feedbackType: feedbacktype
        };
    })();


    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
});
```

### The Goal

- I have a list of buttons.
- When someone clicks on the button, I want to ensure the button they click on becomes 100% opacity, and the rest of the buttons become 30% capacity.

I'm trying to accomplish this by adding an "active" class to the button and removing it from all others, and then performing the fade based on class.

### The Issue

- The first click, it works as expected. The clicked button is at 100% opacity and all others fade.
- The second time, the previously highlighted element fades, but the clicked button doesn't become 100% opacity, despite being given the "active" css class.

  - I added a border-size element to the active class so I could verify this. The clicked item expands its border, but does not fade to 100% opacity.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you already got the right answer, but I would definitely keep the context of `var $target = $(event.currentTarget)` so you can use it later. No sense in selecting the element again with the `$('.btn.active')` business.

Comment: @sfjedi I agree 100%. Glad to have it solved since it was maddening but sticking with addressing it as the target. Thanks for jumping in to clarify that sticking with the target is the better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between the classes, you want to select elements with both classes not `.active` descendants of `.btn`

```
$('.btn .active').fadeTo('fast', 1);
```

should be

```
$('.btn.active').fadeTo('fast', 1);
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwerK/9/)**

Comment: That's it! Keeping the event.currentTarget syntax as I think it makes more sense, but thank you for solving the issue for me (was driving me mad for a few minutes there).